# Bidirectional typing for dependent types: Why are Sigma, Pi synthesized?

Tags: dependent-type, type-inference

According to the [Pfenning philosphy of bidirectional typing](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efp/courses/15312-f04/handouts/15-bidirectional.pdf), as also explained by [Dunfield and Krishnaswamy 2013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6032), constructors should be checked, while eliminators should be synthesized. Cconvention is followed for the most part in the tutorial [Checking Dependent Types with Normalization by Evaluation: A Tutorial
by David Christiansen](http://davidchristiansen.dk/tutorials/nbe/). I cannot explain some choices in the tutorial according to the Pfenning philosophy:

The types `Sigma x A B` and `Pi x A B`, `Nat`, `Eq A from to`, `Trivial`, and `Absurd` are all checked in *synthesis mode*. However, these are *kind constructors*, as they let us construct values that live in `Univ`. Why are they checked in synthesis mode?

Can we view these as eliminators of some object that I am unaware of? As an example of what I mean by this, recall that identifiers such as `x` are also run in synthesis mode. With a bit of squinting, one can convince themselves that identifiers are *projections on the context* `Γ`
, and thus deserve to be run in synthesis mode.

Is there a similar explanation for why `Pi`, `Simga`, `Eq`, `Trivial`, `Absurd` are typed in synthesis mode? what rule-of-thumb does one use to decide whether these should be typed  in checking or synthesis mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, it's not like *constructors* are checked, but *introduction rules* (including tuples, lambdas, data constructors, etc.) are checked (while elimination rules are synthesized). The kind constructors you mentioned are called *formation rules*, which are not introduction rules. You can also think this way: if a *constructor* is checked, then it has a *corresponding eliminator* which is synthesized. If type constructors should be checked, there should be a corresponding thing synthesized. But there's no such thing (you can't pattern match on $\cal U$).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer for that question, I'm afraid.  But I'll just point out that the rule you cite doesn't say that we should use `Γ ⊢ e₁ e₂ ⇒ τ` just because function application is an eliminator.  Instead, it says that within the typing rule for function application, the part that checks the actual function should synthesize (i.e. should be `Γ ⊢ e₁ ⇒ τ₁ → τ₂`), and once you have this, then which of `e₂` and `e₁ e₂` are checked or synthesized are simple/obvious engineering choices.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I misread the explanation. Can you clarify for me the *correct* explanation of which part should be checked and which should be synthesized, in general?